# Graphql is throing an error: Field error in object 'hepatitisLabConditionGroupInput' on field '$.conditionIds': rejected value [null];

Tags: java, graphql, mutation

I am looking a way to pass an Int array to a GraphQL mutation.

I am not sure what I am doing incorrect here.I am getting this error:

> Field error in object 'hepatitisLabConditionGroupInput' on field
> '$.conditionIds': rejected value [null]; codes
> [unknownType.hepatitisLabConditionGroupInput,unknownType]; arguments
> []; default message [Unknown Collection element type]

I am able to pass a single `Int` value, if I change from `[Int]` to just `Int`.

I tried looking online, I think I am passing the Int array correct way. Like here:

`conditionIds:    [77,78]`

Can you please let me know what am I doing incorrectly here?

Here is my GraphQL endpoint:

```
mutation{
  saveHepatitisLabConditionGroup(hepatitisLabConditionGroupInput:{
    groupId: 100
    groupName: "Test 1"
    conditionIds:   [77,78]
  })
}
```

Here is the input and mutation:

```
input HepatitisLabConditionGroupInput{
    groupId: Int
    groupName: String!
    conditionIds: [Int]
}

extend type Mutation{
    saveHepatitisLabConditionGroup (hepatitisLabConditionGroupInput: HepatitisLabConditionGroupInput):Boolean
}
```

Controller starting line:

```
  @MutationMapping
    Boolean saveHepatitisLabConditionGroup(@Argument HepatitisLabConditionGroupInput hepatitisLabConditionGroupInput) {
```

Here is my DTO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HepatitisLabConditionGroupInput {
    Long groupId;
    String groupName;
    Long[] conditionIds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. The fix was to have List , instead of Int [].

So the above code stats as it, with the exception as:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HepatitisLabConditionGroupInput {
    Long groupId;
    String groupName;
    List <Long> conditionIds; 
    // This is invalid: Long [] conditionIds;
}
```

Comment: GraphQL's `Int` corresponds to a 32-bit integer, you should use `int` (or `Integer`) in your Java DTO to match the expected data type (and to save space).
[Scalar Types on graphql.org](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types)